# Shared element transaction with 2 activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-animation

I had 2 activity in which one one **activity_1** I have RecyclerView with images and **activity_2** have view pager with image. I just want to perform image shared element transaction from **activity_1** recycler view to a**ctivity_2** viewpager image as shown in image.
[image]

every thing was working fine except the transaction.
please help

**activity_2 code**

```
     int position = getIntent().getIntExtra(TestActivity.EXTRA_POSITION, 1);
        ArrayList<AnimalItem> filelist = (ArrayList<AnimalItem>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(TestActivity.EXTRA_ANIMAL_ARRAYLIST);
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.animal_view_pager);
        MyCustomPagerAdapter myCustomPagerAdapter = new MyCustomPagerAdapter(PageViewerActivity.this, filelist);
//        myCustomPagerAdapter.getItem(position).setTransitionName(getResources().getString(R.string.transition_contenet_topic));
        viewPager.setAdapter(myCustomPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

**CustomPageAdapter.class**

```
public class MyCustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<AnimalItem> images;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


        public MyCustomPagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AnimalItem> images) {
            this.context = context;
            this.images = images;
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, final int position) {
            View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.test_image_card, container, false);

            ImageView imageView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_main_image);
            Picasso.with(context).load(images.get(position).imageUrl).into(imageView);

            container.addView(itemView);

            //listening to image click
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "you clicked image " + (position + 1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            return itemView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
            container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
        }
    }
```

**activity_1** (on recycler item click code)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PageViewerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_POSITION,pos);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ANIMAL_ARRAYLIST, Utils.generateAnimalItems(getApplicationContext()));
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ANIMAL_IMAGE_TRANSITION_NAME, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(sharedImageView));
    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
            sharedImageView,
            ViewCompat.getTransitionName(sharedImageView));
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

Comment: @NavneetKrishna see my updated question

Comment: Post your `xml` code from activity_1 and activity_2

Answer (score 0):

You may use one activity to achieve this target, And consider `activity_1#RecyclerView` view item as [FlipView](https://github.com/davideas/FlipView), and on top of `flipView imageView` and `viewPager` and on flip action animate `imageView` with `viewPager`.

> ```
> Implementation  'eu.davidea:flipview:1.1.3'
> ```

```
<eu.davidea.flipview.FlipView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/flip_layout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:animateDesignLayoutOnly="true" // This line is important 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Put ImageView  on top to hide ViewPager until flip action -->
    <ImageView  
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ViewPager 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</eu.davidea.flipview.FlipView>
```